# Java socket receives more bytes than expected

Tags: java, sockets, datainputstream

I have just started with Java and am trying to communicate with an external device via TCP/IP. I send a command to the device and receive an appropriate response.

The communication works so far, if I wait 1 second between sending and receiving. What irritates me is that the received data is 7 bytes longer than expected. Before the response are always the bytes 2A 48 45 4C 4C 4F 2A.

I hope that someone can tell me why this is wrong and if I am doing something wrong.

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.40", 80);

    byte[] ba_sendBuffer = new byte[1024];

    // fill sendBuffer

    DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    dOut.writeInt(ba_sendBuffer.length); // write length of the message
    dOut.write(ba_sendBuffer);           // write the message
    dOut.flush();

    // Wait for device
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    byte[] ba_responseBuffer = new byte[0];

    if (socket.isConnected())
    {
        InputStream inFromServer = socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

        synchronized (in)
        {
            int length = in.available();
            ba_responseBuffer = new byte[length];

            in.readFully(ba_responseBuffer);
        }

        // ba_responseBuffer - the first 7 bytes are not expected
        // work with the response
    }
```

Comment: `2A 48 45 4C 4C 4F 2A` is `*HELLO*` in ASCII. I guess you've forgotten some test code...

Comment: You send the length of the buffer before the message, maybe there is the answer.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: you are right with the *HELLO*, but why? My code doesnt' contain the word "hello". I analyzed the data with Wireshark and found that the response from the device does not contain * HELLO *.

Comment: @MladenSavić: the order has no effect.

Comment: so the socket is reading, casually, a "HELLO" by itself? *hhmm..*

Comment: I have just received the answer from a colleague and she is really stupid. I am connected to the device via WIFI and the module always sends a * HELLO * when opening the connection. Question has been settled. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice. You may write an answer on your own or delete the question if you do not expect any answers anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I have just received the answer from a colleague. I am connected to the device via WIFI and the module always sends a * HELLO * when opening the connection. Question has been settled.

Comment: *...a colleague and she is really stupid...* What's her Stackoverlow username?

Comment: I guess you meant that the problem was lame, not that your colleague is stupid xD

Comment: [Be nice](/conduct).

Comment: @SvetlinZarev: Sorry. Yo are right. The problem was stupid/lame, not my colleague. "precision of language" ;-)